# Steps for using existing sass project in Visual Studio

Tags: sass

I've got typescript project which is using sass and compass, but I am having troubles getting it to work in Visual Studio. I have installed ruby, compass using gem command, and Mindscape Workbench, but I don't know how to link all that with my existing project since I've heard for the first time about sass and compass when I started working on this project. I tried to google for solution but it didn't help me much, so if someone can help me I would be very grateful...

Thank you in advance.